# Why is the value 'offset' not saving in this php widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

Why is my 'offset' code not working/saving in this code in wordpress? It was originally dazzling_tabbed_widget (but not any more). If I hard-code 'offset'              => 3 it works fine.

I can't seems to make sense of it.. Here is what I've edited so far:

```
<?php

/**
* Whats Trending Widget
* Dazzling Theme
*/

class dazzling_whats_trending extends WP_Widget {

/**
* Widget setup.
*/
function dazzling_whats_trending() {
/* Widget settings. */
$widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'dazzling_tabbed_widget', 'description' => __( 'Dazzling Whats Trending Widget', 'dazzling' ) );

/* Widget control settings. */
$control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'dazzling_tabbed_widget' );

/* Create the widget. */
parent::__construct( 'dazzling_tabbed_widget', __( 'Dazzling Whats Trending Widget', 'dazzling' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );

}

/**
* How to display the widget on the screen.
*/
 function widget( $args, $instance ) {
extract( $args );

/* Our variables from the widget settings. */
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'number' ] ) )
        $number = $instance[ 'number' ];
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'offset' ] ) )
        $offset= $instance[ 'offset' ];
?>


       <div id="popular-posts" class="sidebar_content tab-pane active">


                <?php
                    $recent_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                        'showposts'           => $number,
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                        'post_status'         => 'publish',
                        'order'               => 'DESC',
                        'meta_key'            => 'post_views_count',
                        'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
                        'offset'              => $offset
                    ) );
                ?>

                <?php while($recent_posts->have_posts()): $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(336,210) ); ?>
              <h4 class="blacktext"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h4>
              <span class="orangetext">
            <?php 
              $post = get_post();
              $views = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_views_count', true);
              if($views > 1000){
                $views_count=$views *1/1000; 
                $views_k=round($views_count,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                echo $views_k.'K';
              }
              else {
                echo $views;
              }
            ?> VIEWS
          </span>
          <span class="graytext">| 
            <?php
              $category = get_the_category(); 
              $category_parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent;
              $category_link = get_category_link($category_parent_id);
              if ( $category_parent_id != 0 ) {
                $category_link = get_category_link($category_parent_id);
                    $category_parent = get_term( $category_parent_id, 'category' );
                    $catname = $category_parent->name;
              } else {
                $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
                    $catname = $category[0]->name;
              }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($category_link); ?>"><?php  echo $catname; ?></a>
          </span>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

         </div>  


<?php
 }
 /**
 * Update the widget settings.
 */
function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance = $old_instance;

/* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
$instance['number'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['number'] );
$instance['offset'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['offset'] );
echo $instance;

return $instance;
}

function form( $instance=array() ) {

    /* Set up some default widget settings. */
    $defaults = array('offset' => 2, 'number' => 3);
    //$defaults = array('number' => 3);
    $instance = wp_parse_args( $instance, $defaults ); ?>

    <!-- Offset posts from -->
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'offset' ); ?>"><?php _e('Offset number of posts by','dazzling') ?>:</label>
      <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'offset' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'offset' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['offset']; ?>" size="3" />
    </p>

    <!-- Number of posts -->
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show','dazzling') ?>:</label>
      <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['number']; ?>" size="3" />
    </p>


  <?php
  }

}
 ?>
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't set `$offset` anywhere.  Look at your line `$number = $instance['number'];` - you need a similar line for `$offset`....

Comment: thanks, like this? <code> /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'number' ] ) )
            $number = $instance[ 'number' ];

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'offset' ] ) )
            $offset = $instance[ 'offset' ];
    ?><code>

Comment: I added my code above and still no go, hmm, am I adding it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I re-made code, using https://pippinsplugins.com/simple-wordpress-widget-template/:

```
<?php
/**
* Example Widget Class
*/
class dazzling_whats_trending extends WP_Widget {


/** constructor -- name this the same as the class above */
function dazzling_whats_trending() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Dazzling Whats Trending Widget');  
}

/** @see WP_Widget::widget -- do not rename this */
function widget($args, $instance) { 
    extract( $args );
    $number    = apply_filters('number', $instance['number']);
    $offset  = $instance['offset'];
    ?>
          <div id="popular-posts" class="sidebar_content tab-pane active">


                <?php
                    $recent_posts = new WP_Query( array(
                        'showposts'           => $number,
                        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                        'post_status'         => 'publish',
                        'order'               => 'DESC',
                        'meta_key'            => 'post_views_count',
                        'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
                        'offset'              => $offset
                    ) );
                ?>

                <?php while($recent_posts->have_posts()): $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(336,210) ); ?>
              <h4 class="blacktext"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h4>
              <span class="orangetext">
            <?php 
              $post = get_post();
              $views = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_views_count', true);
              if($views > 1000){
                $views_count=$views *1/1000; 
                $views_k=round($views_count,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
                echo $views_k.'K';
              }
              else {
                echo $views;
              }
            ?> VIEWS
          </span>
          <span class="graytext">| 
            <?php
              $category = get_the_category(); 
              $category_parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent;
              $category_link = get_category_link($category_parent_id);
              if ( $category_parent_id != 0 ) {
                $category_link = get_category_link($category_parent_id);
                    $category_parent = get_term( $category_parent_id, 'category' );
                    $catname = $category_parent->name;
              } else {
                $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
                    $catname = $category[0]->name;
              }
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($category_link); ?>"><?php  echo $catname; ?></a>
          </span>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

         </div> 
    <?php
}

/** @see WP_Widget::update -- do not rename this */
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {   
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['number'] = strip_tags($new_instance['number']);
$instance['offset'] = strip_tags($new_instance['offset']);
    return $instance;
}

/** @see WP_Widget::form -- do not rename this */
function form($instance) {  


    $number  = esc_attr($instance['number']);
    $offset  = esc_attr($instance['offset']);
    ?>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('offset'); ?>"><?php _e('Offset number of posts by'); ?></label>
      <input size="3" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('offset'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('offset'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $offset; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e('Number of posts to show:'); ?></label> 
      <input size="3" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php 
}


} // end class example_widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("dazzling_whats_trending");'));
?>
```

can't set default numbers yet, but just happy it works :)